# Unable to assign values to new MultiIndex slices (setting with enlargement)

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

Given my data frame *(below)*, I can *individually* create new `MultiIndex` rows that do not exist with

```
data.loc[('A', 6, 'test'), 'Data'] = 'a_value'
```

Similarly, I can modify *slices* that already exist in the `MultiIndex`

```
 data.loc[pd.IndexSlice['A', 7:8, ('spam', 'eggs')], 'Data'] = 'a_value'
```

I am unable to to the following

```
data.loc[pd.IndexSlice['A', (6, 7), ('eggs', 'spam')], 'Data'] = 'a_value'
```

since the `DataFrame` returned by the slice is empty. Is there any way to do this other than iterating through all the non-existing indices individually?

## Example Data

The test DataFrame can be generated by copying the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([np.nan]*2+[np.random.random() for i in range(4)]+[np.nan]*2+[np.random.random(), np.random.random()]),index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B'], [6, 7, 8, 9], [u'eggs', u'spam']], labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], [-1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1]], names=[u'ID', u'ID2', u'ID3']),columns=['Data'])
# end snippet for easy copy/paste to ipython
```

## Similar

[Assign new values to slice from MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833842/assign-new-values-to-slice-from-multiindex-dataframe)

- Note that this is not the same case as this post covers the case of `MultiIndex` slices that are **already in** the `MultiIndex`

Comment: Hmm. This is called 'setting with enlargement', but I'm not sure that it works on slices in general, even without the multiindex.  The documentation only states that it works on a single key.

Comment: Any good workarounds welcome as answers though!

Comment: Well, I'm just poking here ... I don't know enough about it to say if this is possible or if it's a bug, I just know what it's called, hehe.

Comment: @JohnE I'm in the UK so I was asleep ! Your answer was the best possible solution at the current time - you should have left it. I really like the use of `data.index.levels` with the `MultiIndex.from_product`

Comment: sorry about that, I undeleted it

Answer (score 1):

I'm just filling with NaNs but of course you could use `fillna` if you want.  The existing dataframe has some missing values already so it would be a little harder to only give the new rows a non-NaN value but possible using `update`, but I'm not 100% clear on what exactly you are trying to do here.

```
data.reindex( pd.MultiIndex.from_product( data.index.levels ) )

              Data
A 6 eggs       NaN
    spam       NaN
  7 eggs       NaN
    spam       NaN
  8 eggs  0.938516
    spam  0.487062
  9 eggs  0.958066
    spam  0.786476
B 6 eggs       NaN
    spam       NaN
  7 eggs       NaN
    spam       NaN
  8 eggs       NaN
    spam  0.674202
  9 eggs       NaN
    spam  0.576285
```

Comment: The main issue is that I don't necessarily know it is 6,7 that are he missing indices. My current fallback is very similar to the above. Iterating through ID and then using get_index_values("ID3").unique() instead of hardcoding 6,7. Of you add that I'll give an upvote for a best approach. Want to keep open if there are any faster methods as pandas updates

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane  not sure I understand but take a look at my update altho that doesn't fill with values.  Tho I'm not sure why doing it in 2 steps would be much of a problem?